# Dynamic LESS variables from database with Django

Tags: css, django, less

Is there a way to dynamically generate less variable definitions in django? Right now I can do it using css but not while compiling LESS

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845275/django-compressor-with-dynamic-less-file-raises-a-filtererrorerr) implementation looks overly complicated and error prone.

I would ideally like to have a variable in a varaible.less file such as

```
@primary-color: {{ user.primary-color }};
@secondary-color: {{ user.secondary-color }};
```

Comment: Django can render anything. Most people use it to output html, but nothing is stopping you from rendering plain text or Less or JSON, XML etc. When does your Less file get processed to css? What is wrong with an internal stylesheet? Do you KISS?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a view for your variables.less:

```
t = loader.get_template('variables.tpl')
c = Context(user)

return HttpResponse(t.render(c), mimetype="text/css");
```

And import that view in your less code with the url() function:

```
@import (less) url('http://yoursite/variables');
```